# Refresh ng-repeat even nothing has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dom-manipulation

I make some dom-manipulation inside a `ng-repeat`. Now I want to reset my DOM to match the model where `ng-repeat` is looping over. How can I force AngularJS to redraw the `ng-repeat` content.

Apply doesn't work obviously cause no changes where made to the model.

Comment: code... code... code...

Comment: Why would you like to re-run a ng-repeat when no data has been changed? DOM manipulations can be done using directives, that's what they have been 'designed' for. Just wondering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of `ng-repeat` is that it follows the model. If you want to change the content you should really change the model. As for the dom-manipulations, you should perform those within an angular component or directive and again, make it follow the model.

If you're not doing that, you pretty much might as well not use Angular at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14648517)

Comment: Well actually, I'm telling him to use directives/components for the dom manipulations so he can use the model als leading source, which is an answer to the question 'how can I force ....' that is asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste some code, would be great, but anyway  for example lets say we have this:

```
$scope.rows = [1,2,3];

<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
   {{row}}
</div>
```

In order to redraw the same data with `ng-repeat` you need to somehow change the scope. You can try this after your DOM manipilation

```
$scope.rows = angular.copy($scope.rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to do any special things to re bind the DOM in angular js. Angular JS supports [two way data binding](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp), so when ever your model changes, the DOM object rebinds automatically with modified contents. So all you have to do is rebind your controller variable, that will automatically updates the DOM.